# How to cascade delete in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I delete file.txt when I delete Folder1 in mongoDB and nodejs ?

```
[
 {
  _id: 1,
  name: Folder1,
  parentId: null
 },
{
  _id: 2,
  name: file.txt,
  parentId: 1
 },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Delete a Document  , for example
You can specify the document or documents to be deleted by the deleteOne() or deleteMany() write operations in a JSON object as follows:

```
const doc = {
  pageViews: {
    $gt: 10,
    $lt: 32768
  }
};
```

To delete the first matching document using the deleteOne() method or to delete all matching documents using the deleteMany() method, pass the document as the method parameter:

```
const deleteResult = await collection.deleteOne(doc);
const deleteManyResult = await collection.deleteMany(doc);
```

[enter link description here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/delete/#delete-a-document)